# Как получить количество уникальных посетителей сайта?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет! У меня есть база данных, в которую я сохраняю посещения сайта.
Структура базы следующую: id | ip | os | browser | url | date

Задача такая, чтобы получить уникальных посетителей по IP. То есть посчитать количество строк в таблице, где ip = уникальному.

Попробовал сделать это с помощью GROUP BY, но в итоге я получаю уникальные IP в базе и количество посещений с них.

```css
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `visitors` GROUP BY `ip`
```

Мне же в свою очередь надо просто получить количество уникальных IP адресов в таблице. Как это сделать?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(distinct ip) FROM `visitors`

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимый запрос к MySQL для решения моей задачи был:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct ip) FROM visitors
```

Спасибо @splash58